# Error when I clear the snap which is taken by webcam

Tags: python, django

I have attached webcam in my django admin project
when I click on "take snapshot" button and click on "save"
my snap has saved but when I try to click on "clear" button
and try to save it shows me a error "Incorrect padding"
 my code for webcam is

```
import webcam.admin
from webcam import widgets
from webcam.fields import CameraField


picture=CameraField('Webcam_Image', format='jpeg', null=True, blank=True, upload_to='pictures')
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: The error message says"Incorrect padding".

Comment: This error comes because when i clear the saved image from my django admin  it temporarily deletes it but saved image still remains in directory.